# How to append result to a dataframe from another dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames:

```
df2 = Srno, Unique, %count, TotalCount, Values
       1,     B   ,       ,           ,40
       2,     A   ,       ,           ,45
       3,     D   ,       ,           ,56  
       4,     C   ,       ,           ,60      

df1 = Srno, Unique, %count, TotalCount
        1,     A   , 35%,    89
        2,     B   , 40%     65           
        3,     C   , 42%     42         
        4,     D   , 15%     80
```

I want to insert the columns `%count` and `TotalCount` from `df1` to `df2` on the basis of column `Unique`.

I tried the following, but it does not give me the output I am looking for:

```py
df2['%count'] = df1[df1['Unique'].isin(df2['Unique'])]['%count'].values
```

I want the following output:

```
df2 = Srno, Unique, %count, TotalCount, Values
        1,     B   , 40%  ,    65       ,40
        2,     A   , 35%  ,    89       ,45
        3,     D   , 15%  ,    80       ,56  
        4,     C   , 42%  ,    42       ,60
```

---

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Srno': [1, 2, 3, 4],
        'Unique': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
        r'%count': ['35%', '40%', '42%', '15%'],
        'TotalCount': [89, 65, 42, 80],
    }
)


df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Srno': [1, 2, 3, 4],
        'Unique': ['B', 'A', 'D', 'C'],
        r'%count': ['', '', '', ''],
        'TotalCount': ['', '', '', ''],
        'Values': [40, 45, 56, 60],
    }
)

expected_output = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Unique': ['B', 'A', 'D', 'C'],
        r'%count': ['40%', '35%', '15%', '42%'],
        'TotalCount': [65, 89, 80, 42],
        'Values': [40, 45, 56, 60],
    }
)
```

Comment: 1. Could you provide the minimum code to generate the minimum sample input data for your query? 2. Please show what is your expected output is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have `NaN` in both columns, you can try with [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) :

```
df2 = (df1.set_index("Unique")[["%count", "TotalCount"]]
           .combine_first(df2.set_index("Unique")).reset_index()
           .reindex(columns=df2.columns).sort_values(by="Srno")
      )
```

Output :

```
print(df2)

   Srno Unique %count  TotalCount  Values
1     1      B    40%          65      40
0     2      A    35%          89      45
3     3      D    15%          80      56
2     4      C    42%          42      60
```

Comment: **NB** : If both columns hold *empty strings*, run this first : `df2 = df2.replace("", np.NaN)`